# How do HTML parsers process text outside elements (text nodes)

Tags: html, dom, html-parsing

Ref this question:

[Add html tag to string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52159323/add-html-tag-to-string-in-php/52162629#comment91289440_52162629)

Questioner asks how to properly detect untagged text in a HTML file, ( he wanted to insert tags as needed). He provided this example:

```
<h2><b>Hello World</b></h2>
<p>First</p>
Second
<p>Third</p>
```

(Of course to solve the particular problem presented is a matter of some text find/replace - with complexity enough to meet the expected use cases. The question poser himself proceeded in this manner).

My question is this:

1. What does the latest HTML5 standard say about untagged text and how it should be treated?
2. How do current HTML parsers treat untagged text.
3. Could the problem in question in SO52159323 have been solved using an HTMLParser class (in whatever language). I mean by running the text past the parser and expecting the parser to identify the untagged text and its location? I tried this and failed!

PS I know that HTML aware browsers and editors just echo untagged text, and at least in the case of Chrome, by observation using the dev tools it does not attempt to create any kind of default element - the untagged text just sits there like a dead duck!

Comment: The `Second` text in the markup snippet in the question just gets added to the DOM as a text node (including the newlines before it and after it). That’s all. It gets added to the DOM after the `p` element node created by `<p>First</p>` and before the `p` element node created by `<p>Third</p>`. So you end up with an `p` element node followed by that text node followed by another `p` element node. That’s what the HTML spec says should happen and that’s what all HTML parsers do with it.

Comment: The “problem” in that other question cannot be solved by just running the source through an HTML parser. HTML parsers don’t do any magic to try to change text nodes into element nodes based on the fact the text node happens to be between two element nodes that have the same element name, or anything like that. If you have a text node like that in the source, the parser is just going to create a text node for it in the DOM.

Comment: Imagine what would happen if you tried to make a tool that otherwise attempted to guess, every time it found a text node in the source, you actually wanted it to instead be some element with that text inside it. How would your tool distinguish the case where you really really do want a text node between two elements? Anyway, regardless, HTML parsers on their own don’t do any kind of heuristics like that to try to figure out what you might have wanted. They just use exactly what you feed them.

Comment: @sideshowbarker. Thanks for this. I surely did not expect the parse to try to guess what to do, but I failed to see the "text node" in any node collection after processing by HTML parser. Admittedly was using PHP based. If I used a Javascript parser, would I expect to see the "text node" in a collection or whatever, including a node type? Pretty please a code snippet? Also I am first to admit my knowledge of DoM is less than complete, as my understanding of "text node" was the text contained in a element - which this is obviously not - or not restricted to that.

Comment: @sideshowbarker. Also I would like to frame an answer to this, when I have done thrashing about - I have no problem to prepare draft for you which I will accept - upvote etc.

Comment: @sideshowbarker. OK! I suspected that there was something "off" in how I perceived this topic. That something is looking at the HTML fragment in isolation. Normally the fragment would be enclosed at least in <body> tags, so any free floating text would be child text nodes of the <body> element node. I will read up some more, on DoM terminology, and also look a bit deeper as to what constitutes well formed HTML, and from there look see how Chrome etc and other parsers deal with badly formed HTML documents. Then decide if question like this has general interest or not.... Thank you again.

Comment: Right — any text node in an HTML document is necessarily within some element node. So in the markup snippet in the question, that text node is part of the content of whatever element is the parent node of the h2 element. And incidentally, the `<body>` start tag is optional, so even if there’s no `<body>` start tag in the source, the HTML parser will create a `body` element in the DOM — and then any text node that’s not a child of some other element in the source becomes a child of the `body` in the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't suppose anyone else will post a reply so for the record I am recording here what I learned from the comments and sound advice of  **sideshowbarker**

> What does the latest HTML5 standard say about untagged text and how it
>   should be treated?

Untagged text is entered into the DoM as a text node. The text node is inserted as a child node of the element in which it appears. For example in this snippet:

```
<body>
    <h2><b>Hello World</b></h2>
    <p>First</p>
    Second
    <p>Third</p>
</body>
```

... "Second" is **part** of a **text node** (nodeType=3) which is a child node of the body element.

In fact there are 4 child text nodes (nodeValues of each shown in list below).

1. `"CR-LF    "`  after the opening **body** tag.
2. `"CR-LF    "`  after the `<h2><b>Hello World</b></h2>` element
3. `"CR-LF    Second-CR-LF   "` after the `<p>First</p>` element
4. `"CR-LF    "` after the `<p>Third</p>` element

Probably most "uglifiers" will remove the CR_LF and spaces from text node, which in most cases can remove them altogether.

> How do current HTML parsers treat untagged text?

As above, but with at least these qualifiers:

1. untagged text (be it formatting or alphanumeric or both) between the `<html>` tags but outside the `<body>` tags, will be moved inside the `<body>` element.
2. If `<body>` tags are missing the parser will insert them.

For example, using **PHPDocument** (PHP inbuilt Dom parser) this input..

```
<html>
    text before body
<body>
    <h2><b>Hello World</b></h2>
    <p>First</p>
    Second
    <p>Third</p>
    fourth
    <p>Third</p>
    <!-- comment -->
</body>
    text after body
</html>
```

..produced this DoM (untagged text moved into the `<body>` element).

```
<html><body>
<p>
    text before body
</p>
    <h2><b>Hello World</b></h2>
    <p>First</p>
    Second
    <p>Third</p>
    fourth
    <p>Third</p>
    <!-- comment -->

    text after body
</body></html>
```

and this input..

```
<html>
    <h2><b>Hello World</b></h2>
    <p>First</p>
    Second
    <p>Third</p>
    fourth
    <p>Third</p>
    <!-- comment -->
</html>
```

..produced this DoM (`<body>` tags inserted by the parser)

```
    <html>
    <body>
<h2><b>Hello World</b></h2>
    <p>First</p>
    Second
    <p>Third</p>
    fourth
    <p>Third</p>
    <!-- comment -->
</body>
</html>
```

> Could the problem in question in SO52159323 have been solved using an
>   HTMLParser class (in whatever language). I mean by running the text
>   past the parser and expecting the parser to identify the untagged text
>   and its location?

Yes. See code fragment in my answer at [Add html tag to string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52159323/add-html-tag-to-string-in-php/52200827). Of course the parser produces the DoM making it possible to search out candidate node and doing the required processing.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I replied to my own question, based on your valuable comments and advice.  As I said earlier I am happy to consider this as a draft for submission as your work - given the clarity of your comments, or feel free to edit if I have got anything wrong.