# How to count all nodes in DOMDocument

Tags: php

Using PHP 7.1 I want to count the number of nodes in the root of this string:

```
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<div>Dolores</div>
<b>Amet</b>
```

Using following PHP:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$root = $dom->documentElement;
$children = $root->childNodes;
var_dump($children)
```

Returns:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#4 (1) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

I don't understand why the string of HTML only returns as 1 node. Additionally, I am unable to iterate through the nodes.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471073/php-dom-counting-child-nodes

Comment: Does $content contains the html code above???

Comment: @Sigma Yes, it does.

Comment: @EquaPro Thanks, but all examples show exact knowledge of type of node. I intentionally picked different types of nodes in the HTML.

Comment: testing it, on my environment it returns: object(DOMNodeList)[3]
  public 'length' => int 1... ?? strange

Comment: What do you exactly expect as result??? I modified it somehow and im getting 6 as result but still strange even the p tag is considered as repeat and counted once so in total are 6 different tags counting open and close, but i'm counting the tags assuming is what you are referring as nodes.

Comment: @Sigma The answer should be 4, because there are 4 nodes shown above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181580/discussion-between-sigma-and-bart).

Comment: `echo $dom->saveHTML();` and note how the output is different from your input, because of how it adds things to generate a valid DOM. You're getting a length of 1 because it's counting the single `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record ( and despite other answer being accepted, here is the correct way to list the child **nodes** :-).  This includes the text nodes, which people forget are there!

```
<?php

$content = " 
  <p>Lorem</p> 
  <p>Ipsum</p> 
  <div>Dolores</div> 
  <b>Amet</b> 
 ";

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$nodes=[];
$bodyNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');  // returns DOMNodeList object
foreach($bodyNodes[0]->childNodes as $child)      // assuming 1 <body> node
{
    $nodes[]=$child->nodeName;
}

print_r($nodes);
```

Outputs this, illustrating the point...:

```
Array
(
    [0] => p
    [1] => #text
    [2] => p
    [3] => #text
    [4] => div
    [5] => #text
    [6] => b
    [7] => #text
)
```

Comment: A +1 for pedantry ;)

Comment: I tore my hair out a few weeks ago wondering where the extra (invisible text) nodes were coming from, making me super-sensitive on this topic :-)

Comment: Thanks! The trick thing is that HTML and BODY nodes are being added automatically by loadHTML(), which allows you to perform getElementsByTagName('body'). I was stuck there.

Comment: Here is where I cut my teeth on this subject. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52176319/how-do-html-parsers-process-untagged-text   I ended up answering my own question in the end....

Answer (score 3):

After a nice conversation in chat with @bart we find a solution.

```
$content = " 
  <p>Lorem</p> 
  <p>Ipsum</p> 
  <div>Dolores</div> 
  <b>Amet</b> 
 ";

  $dom = new DOMDocument;
  $dom->loadHTML($content);
  $allElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
  echo $allElements->length;

  echo "<br />";

  $node = array();
  foreach($allElements as $element) {
      if(array_key_exists($element->tagName, $node)) {
          $node[$element->tagName] += 1;
      } else {
           $node[$element->tagName] = 1;
         }
  }
  print_r($node);
```

ps: html and body tag are added and counted by default increasing the result by 2.

Comment: I just added an (admittedly redundant) answer, note the second argument to `DOMDocument::loadHTML()` which suppresses the creation of additional elements and such.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this reply counts the number of child elements not child nodes, although I am sure this is what OP intended (but he said NODES). However, if its a struct node count you want you have add in all the text nodes - excluded from the above reply!

Answer (score 2):

Well I was already typing this answer up so I'll add it here anyway.

You have to iterate through the contents of a [`DOMNodeList` object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), it's not an array structure that can be seen with `var_dump()` and friends. When iterating with `foreach` you get an instance of a [`DOMNode` object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php). The count of elements in the `DOMNodeList` is stored in the `length` property.

```
$content = " 
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<div>Dolores</div>
<b>Amet</b>
";

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$allElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
echo "We found $allElements->length elements\n";

foreach ($allElements as $element) {
    echo "$element->tagName = $element->nodeValue\n";
}
```

Comment: Your answer still has a lot of value, for example the flags LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED and LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD are helpful.